# Is there a difference between leave open/leave closed and skip

Tags: support, reviewing

To reopen or close a question it needs 5 votes cast in favor of the suggestion (or a mod uses their cheat codes). When I review a question that has been nominated for reopen or to be closed, whether I say specifically "No" to the suggestion by choosing the "keep open/close" button or say "I can't decide on the matter" by clicking skip, the question doesn't get my close/reopen vote, so it seems to me that it doesn't really matter, or to quote the street fighter movie:

> If good men do nothing, that is evil enough

Is there any difference between choosing "Keep question open/closed" and "skip"?

Comment: Please tell me you're joking re: Street Fighter. Please. I don't know if I can take much more after the Bioshock/Skyrim idiots.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz, it's a quote from the street fighter movie, those were the last words of Dhalsim, when he chose to stay in Shadaloo alongside with Blanka, so I don't see the problem there, If you are referring to the fact that I chose to quote that peace of cinematographic "masterpiece", and not some dead boring Irish philosopher, it's also on purpose. After all, this is a gaming site, not a political philosophy site.

Comment: Hey.... I love boring Irish philosophers.  *There is no knowledge that is not power.  -Shao Khan, Mortal Kombat 3*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see the details [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/139836/166936) but basically Leave Open/Closed will remove the item from the review queues after 3 "leave" votes (or one mod leave vote) and the votes will start to age as if the question had 100 views, even if it doesn't. So if a question gets 3 leave open/closed votes it's less likely to actually be closed, as the votes will start to age and less attention (from the review queue) will be put on it.

Edit apparently also counts as "Leave Open" when selected as an option from the review queue. If necessary you can open the link to the post in a separate window, click Close and then edit the post to avoid leaving a "leave open" vote when you don't believe your edits make the post worthy of staying open.

Comment: Does choosing 'Edit' count as 'Leave Open'?

Comment: @galacticninja I don't think so, I think Leave Open remains as an option...Edit does throw close posts into the Reopen queue though. And there's an "edit and reopen" button in Review (which leads me to believe they're otherwise separate).

Comment: It seems that 'Edit' will count as 'Leave Open' in the close vote review queue, [as per a reply to me by a moderator at MSO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139834/what-exactly-happens-with-the-button-leave-open-previously-do-not-close/139836#comment527201_139836).